# QGIS as Spatial Database RAD or Hierarchical Attribute Viewer/Editor?

Tags: qgis, postgresql, geology, postgis-2.2

I have designed a geological observational spatial database in PostgreSQL/PostGIS to manage geochemical samples, QAQC and geological map objects.  Now is the not so fun/easy part of designing a front end to manage all the 1:1 and 1:Many related tables.  I have extensive experience with MS Access database forms design but besides that my GUI programing is limited.

I am looking for a multi-platform database RAD (Windows/Linux/IOS/etc) so I am leaning towards something with python.  I was looking at Dabo  (http://dabodev.com/) at first but it seems to be quite a slow to stagnate development.

So what are the opinions of using QGIS as the spatial database attributes front end manager and of course spatial display & editing?  How difficult will it be to design a relatively complicated database application in QGIS?

On another hand one really nice feature of ArcGIS is its hierarchical attribute information & editor tool for dealing with multiple 1:1 & 1:many related tables.  Does QGIS have anything similar?  That would be nice to begin the database model testing.

Comment: LibreOffice has a PostgreSQL driver... https://wiki.documentfoundation.org/PostgreSQL-SDBC There are forms and other data editing tools available from LibreOffice Base...